# Regex re.compile not working on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, regex

I'm using jupyter notebook to do some simple Regex patterns but it keeps returning none for these two cases and I can’t see why.

1. I want to search for 3 to 5 digits pattern

```py
    digitRegex = re.compile('r(\d){3,5}')
    digitRegex.search('123456789')
```

should return '12345' but it returns none :(

2. Same problem here, when trying to find 3 consecutive US phone numbers and I want optional: area code and separated by a comma

```py
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'((\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,)?){3}')

phoneRegex.search('My numbers are 415-555-1234,555-4242,212-555-000')
```

should return the 3 phone numbers but also returns none :(

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, you put the `r` prefix *inside* the string, so it won't work. (Such prefix are used for raw strings.)

Working code:

```
digitRegex = re.compile(r'\d{3,5}')
digitRegex.search('123456789')
```

In the second sample, the string won't match because it attempts to get three phone numbers at all and the last one ends with three figures instead of four. You need to fix either your regexp or your phone number.

- Working sample with **valid numbers** matching the **original regex**:

  ```
  phoneRegex = re.compile(r'((\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,)?){3}')
  phoneRegex.search('My numbers are 415-555-1234,555-4242,212-555-0000')
  ```
- Working sample with a **edited regex** matching the **original numbers**:

  ```
  phoneRegex = re.compile(r'((\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d?(,)?){3,4}')
  phoneRegex.search('My numbers are 415-555-1234,555-4242,212-555-0000')
  ```